# batch for loop not iterating beyond first entry

Tags: windows, batch-file

My problem is pretty simple, but I'm unsure why I am seeing this behaviour. I want to get a list of parameters down to a single entry at a time so I can do some processing on them. The list of jar files I am processing is separated by a `;` delimiter.

```
set JARS=this.jar;that.jar;and.jar;the.jar;other.jar
for /f "delims=;" %%a in ("%JARS%") do echo.%%a
```

I'm expecting the script to exit listing as follows.

```
this.jar
that.jar
and.jar
the.jar
other.jar
C:\>
```

But the script is instead exiting as follows.

```
this.jar
C:\>
```

I'm clearly missing something obvious, but I can't seem to see it.

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: `FOR /F` will parse the content line by line first, then use the delimiter to separate the line into tokens. In your case, the content of `JARS` is on a single line, so you only get the first token.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Foxidrive's answer is saying the same as you mention, but the answer is still not right. Any thoughts on how I can tokenize a single line?

Comment: I am getting the expected output with @foxidrive's answer. What kind of output are you getting?

Comment: Strange. I just tried again and it worked. I must have had something else playing up and confused myself with the answer. Thanks!

Comment: You should also upvote foxidrive's answer if it helped you. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: The semicolon is a separator on a command line so it will delimit the filenames.

```
set JARS=this.jar;that.jar;and.jar;the.jar;other.jar
for %%a in (%JARS%) do echo.%%a
```